# How to run all the subs on every slide in powerpoint 2010?

Tags: vba, combobox, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I am creating slides with combo-boxes. I get what I want when I run the codes of each slide individually in debug mode.

I want to write a macro which will run all the subs on all the slides when I run the presentation? Should I use the Call function?

Comment: A general suggestion:  Put the code in a module, not in the controls themselves.  Another button on the slide can invoke the code, which can do whatever you need it to.